# Questions about confidence intervals

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

I'm working on some homework and cannot figure out this question so I thought I'd come here for some help.

> Part 1: A recent study of food portion sizes reported that over a 17-year period, the average size of a soft drink consumed by Americans aged 2 years and older increased from 13.1 ounces (oz) to 19.9 oz. The authors state that the difference is statistically significant with P < 0.01. Explain what additional information you would need to compute a confidence interval for the increase, and outline the procedure that you would use for the computations. (Select all that apply.)
>
> a.) t and degrees of freedom could be used to find the confidence interval. In this case we could compute SED and use degrees of freedom to find t*.
>
> b.) Standard deviations and degrees of freedom could be used to find the confidence interval. In this case we could now find the P-value, which could be used to find SED.
>
> c.) Sample sizes and a more accurate P-value could be used to find the confidence interval. In this case we could determine standard deviations and the confidence interval in the usual way.
>
> d.) Degrees of freedom and a more accurate P-value could be used to find the confidence interval. In this case we could determine t, then calculate SED and t*.
>
> e.) Sample sizes and standard deviations could be used to find the confidence interval. In this case we could find the interval in the usual way.

---

> Part 2: Do you think that a confidence interval would provide useful additional information? Explain why or why not.
>
> a.) Yes, the confidence interval could give us useful information about the average size of soft drinks.
>
> b.) Yes, the confidence interval could give us useful information about the variability between sample participants in the study.
>
> c.) Yes, the confidence interval could give us useful information about the magnitude of the difference.
>
> d.) No, the confidence interval could give us no more useful information because it cannot tell us the sample size in the study.
>
> e.) No, the confidence interval could give us no more useful information because the P-value already tells us that the interval does not contain 0.

For part 1, I think a is among the correct answers, but I can't tell if any others would work as well. And for part 2, I've eliminated b as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

For part 2 the answer is c because the confidence interval can tell us just how different the averages are and that is what we are looking for, magnitude.

I'm still trying to figure out part 1